# How to capture trackers like cookies, pixels, etc., used on a remote website?

Tags: cookies, bots, tracking, privacy

We are working on a project similar to CookieBot as part of a larger project to protect personal data and information of web users. The aim is to obtain comprehensive information about tracking and profiling techniques so that the user can decide for themselves whether to allow their use. But prior owner of website has to know it.

How can we access a website in such a way that we can intercept requests and cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with [puppeteer](/questions/tagged/puppeteer) which allows you to script Chrome (or Chromium) via JavaScript.

In this example:

1. I go to this page
2. I print all requests going out from this page
3. I print all cookies set page this page

```js
// pptr.js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');

module.exports = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.connect({ browserWSEndpoint: 'ws://localhost:3001' });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.on('request', req => {
    console.log(`request: ${req.url()}`);
  });
  await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com/q/64901406/1244884');
  const cookies = await page.cookies();
  console.log('Cookies:');
  cookies.forEach(cookie => {
    console.log(`${cookie.name}\t${cookie.value}`);
  });
  await browser.close();
};
```

Which you can run as follow:

```
node -p -e 'require("./pptr.js")()'
```

Output:

```
request: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64901406/1244884
request: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901406/how-to-capture-trackers-like-cookies-pixels-etc-used-on-a-remote-website
request: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js
request: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=e10313546043
request: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css?v=3b16a418cc4c
request: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/primary.css?v=8cf2d7217e38
request: https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/79435cc2571ffa23dfcef703f8d762e0?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG
request: https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/f7c922ac3a9edef38d31baf959088f77?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1
request: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg?v=fcc0ea44ba27
request: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=f4676f10d215
request: https://cdn.sstatic.net/clc/clc.min.js?v=d7c7e62bd2f5
request: https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js
request: https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
request: https://secure.quantserve.com/quant.js
request: https://sb.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js
request: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full-anon.en.js?v=2d9c6897045f
request: https://cdn.sstatic.net/clc/styles/clc.min.css?v=83419f27e8fa
request: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/post-validation.en.js?v=2589ce0a8248
request: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64901406/ivc/6697?_=1605741791032
request: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/wmd-buttons.svg?v=c26278fc22d9
request: https://rules.quantcount.com/rules-p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc.js
request: https://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel;r=1818481277;rf=0;uht=2;a=p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc;url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F64901406%2Fhow-to-capture-trackers-like-cookies-pixels-etc-used-on-a-remote-website;fpan=1;fpa=P0-221458664-1605741791402;ns=0;ce=1;qjs=1;qv=3364aec3-20201006003021;cm=;gdpr=0;ref=;d=stackoverflow.com;je=0;sr=800x600x24;dst=0;et=1605741791401;tzo=0;ogl=type.website%2Curl.https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow%252Ecom%2Fquestions%2F64901406%2Fhow-to-capture-trackers-like-cookie%2Csite_name.Stack%20Overflow%2Cimage.https%3A%2F%2Fcdn%252Esstatic%252Enet%2FSites%2Fstackoverflow%2FImg%2Fapple-touch-icon%402%252Epng%3Fv%3D73d79a8%2Ctitle.How%20to%20capture%20trackers%20like%20cookies%252C%20pixels%252C%20etc%252E%252C%20used%20on%20a%20remote%20website%3F%2Cdescription.We%20are%20working%20on%20a%20project%20similar%20to%20CookieBot%20as%20part%20of%20a%20larger%20project%20to%20
Cookies:
__qca   P0-221458664-1605741791402
prov    d91ccb9e-35d8-78ff-61b2-2c157d6d65c7
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly like charm. I just combined your solution with PuPHPeteer and voilà... You and StackOverflow saved ma life! Thanks all and especially customcommander for your time effort. I appreciate that very much!

Comment: @McNezmo Please share back with us the result of your research.